# PDF corrompido após download?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, express.js, download

Estou gerando PDF's dos dados que possuo numa tabela no meu cliente, envio os dados para o servidor e lá é gerado o PDF. Após ele estar pronto, ocorre o download do PDF, e é nessa etapa do processo que ele corrompe.

Porém, se antes de eu fazer o download dele eu abrir manualmente, ele abre sem problemas nenhum, com os mesmos dados que estavam na tabela, ou seja, ele está corrompendo quando faço o download, segue os códigos abaixo:

Servidor:

```
let filePath = "C:/Projetos/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf"; 
let fileName = 'PDF.pdf'; 
res.download(filePath, fileName);
```

Cliente:

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/server/gerarpdf',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      data: this.pessoas
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = 'TabelaTeste.pdf'
      link.click()
    })
```

Se alguém souber o que está corrompendo o PDF agradeço...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema que causava o corrompimento do PDF era bem simples: se tratava de uma função assíncrona e o PDF estava sendo enviado antes mesmo de estar pronto, segue código com a solução para o problema:

```
pdfMake = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
let stream = pdfMake.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../pdfs/Tabela.pdf'));
pdfMake.end();

stream.on('finish', function() {
    if (fs.existsSync('C:/Projetos/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf')) {
        let file = 'C:/Projetos/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf';
        res.download(file);
    }
})
```

Após isso o PDF até era baixado com o nome certo...

Comment: Vlw por compartilhar! ;)

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar, pois já recebi muita ajuda aqui, apenas quero retribuir da melhor forma